# How do i make a port using my phone

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

**how do i make a port so i can get url to the device tree.**
I searched on the internet how to do it and *nothing helped me*. I asked for this on *xda-developers* and no answer.

Comment: I think a lot of information was present in the Cyanogenmod Wiki (wiki.cyanogenmod.org) which has been shut down on Dec 2016. You may be able obtain certain pages using [Wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php).

Comment: ask this question on stackoverflow meta that will help i think

Comment: @Robert and how do i find the correct page with non-functional search bar?!

Comment: Google hat it all in it's index. Just limit the site you are searching in.